# Long wavelength limit of sound wave

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, acoustics

I often heard the statement that *the deformation of the system corresponding to a sound wave in the limit $k\rightarrow 0$ must go over into a displacement of the system as a whole.* I don't understand this statement well. Is there any clear picture for this? Sorry for my stupid question.

---

For example, in page 165 of *Statistical Physics of Particles*, Mehran Kardar, about vibration of solid.
[image]

Comment: Please quote a reference with context. Assuming $k$ is the wavenumber, this probably means to say that a sound wave with a frequency of 0 Hz is just a static pressure change (or displacement change) in the medium but without some context that's hard to tell

Comment: Just as your comment, but I do not understant why zero frequency is a displacement. Can you explain this with more details. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have this book. Can you post a life reference? I think this depends  a lot on whether, for example, you are talking about a plane wave or a spherical wave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A Short Answer**

Sound wave (or crystal vibration) is described in terms of the displacement of each atom from its equilibrium position. This displacement has the form
$$ u_n=Ae^{i(kx_n^0-\omega t)}$$

Then, the position of the $n^{th}$ atom is given by $x_n=x_n^0+u_n$ where $x_n^0$ is the equilibrium position of atom $n$. At $k=0$, the displacement is independent of the position, it is
$$ u_n(k=0)=Ae^{-i\omega t}$$
which means that at any time $t$, all atoms are displaced by the same quantity which you can think of as moving the whole solid by the same amount.

You can take a look at *Introduction to Solid State Physics, by Kittel, C.* [chapter 4] or *Solid State Physics, by Ashcroft and Merin* for more.

Comment: Clear explaination!